# The method 'toDate' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: toDate() ,Is there any solution to get rod of this error. i am new to firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, chat

here is my homepage code.

```
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:vip_chat/chat_room.dart';
    import 'package:vip_chat/fireBaseHelper.dart';
    import 'package:vip_chat/model/chatRoom_model.dart';
    import 'package:vip_chat/search_page.dart';

    import 'model/messages_model.dart';
    import 'model/user_model.dart';

    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      final userModel usermodel;
      final User firebasebaseUser;

      const HomePage({super.key, required this.usermodel, required this.firebasebaseUser});


      @override
      State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
    }

    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text('VIP Chat App'),
          ),body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chatrooms').where('participants.${widget.usermodel.uid}',isEqualTo: true).snapshots(),
              builder: (context,snapshot){
                if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.active){
                  if(snapshot.hasData){
                    QuerySnapshot dataSnapshot=snapshot.data as QuerySnapshot;
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: dataSnapshot.docs.length,itemBuilder: (context,index){
                        MessageModel currentMessage=MessageModel.fromMap(dataSnapshot.docs[index].data() as Map<String,dynamic>);
                        ChatRoomModel chatroommodel=ChatRoomModel.fromMap(dataSnapshot.docs[index].data()as Map<String,dynamic>);
                        Map<String,dynamic>participants=chatroommodel.participants!;
                        List<String>partkeys=participants.keys.toList();
                        partkeys.remove(widget.usermodel.uid);
                        return FutureBuilder(future: FireBaseHelper.getUsermodel(partkeys[0]),builder: (context,userData){

                          if(userData.connectionState==ConnectionState.done){
                            if(userData.data!=null){
                              userModel targetUser=userData as userModel;
                              return ListTile(
                                onTap: (){
                                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
                                    return ChatRoomPage(targetUser: targetUser, chatroom: chatroommodel, usermodel: widget.usermodel, firebaseuser: widget.firebasebaseUser);
                                  }));
                                },
                                title: Text(targetUser.fullName.toString()),
                                subtitle: Text(chatroommodel.lastMessage.toString()),
                                leading: CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: NetworkImage(targetUser.profilepic.toString()),),

                              );
                            }
                            else{
                              return Container();
                            }

                          }else{
                            return Container();
                          }

                          },);
                      },);
                  }
                  else if(snapshot.hasError){
                    return Center(child: Text('An error occurred!'));
                  }
                  else{
                    return Center(
                      child: Text('No chats'),
                    );
                  }
                }else{
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){return SearchPage(usermodel: widget.usermodel, firebaseuser:widget.firebasebaseUser );}));
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.search),
          ),
        );

      }
    }
```

// chatRoom model class page

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class MessageModel{
      String?messageid;
      String? sender;
      String?text;
      bool?seen;
      DateTime?createdon;
    
      MessageModel({this.sender,this.text,this.seen,this.createdon,this.messageid});
    
      MessageModel.fromMap(Map<String,dynamic>map){
        messageid=map['messageid'];
        sender=map['sender'];
        text=map['text'];
        seen=map['seen'];
        createdon=map['createdon'].toDate();
    
    
      }
    
      Map<String,dynamic>toMap(){
        return{
          'messageid':messageid,
          'sender':sender,
          'text':text,
          'seen':seen,
          'createdon':createdon
    
        };
      }
    
    
    
    }
```

//ChatPage code

```
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:vip_chat/main.dart';
    import 'package:vip_chat/model/chatRoom_model.dart';
    import 'package:vip_chat/model/messages_model.dart';
    
    import 'model/user_model.dart';
    class ChatRoomPage extends StatefulWidget {
      final userModel targetUser;
      final ChatRoomModel chatroom;
      final userModel usermodel;
      final User firebaseuser;
    
      const ChatRoomPage({super.key, required this.targetUser, required this.chatroom, required this.usermodel, required this.firebaseuser});
    
    
    
      @override
      State<ChatRoomPage> createState() => _ChatRoomPageState();
    }
    
    class _ChatRoomPageState extends State<ChatRoomPage> {
      TextEditingController messagecontroller=TextEditingController();
      void sendMessage() async{
        String msg=messagecontroller.text.trim();
        messagecontroller.clear();
        if(msg!=''){
          MessageModel newMessage=MessageModel(
            messageid: uuid.v1(),
            sender: widget.usermodel.uid,
            createdon: DateTime.now(),
            text: msg,
            seen: false
          );
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chatrooms').doc(widget.chatroom.chatroomid).collection('messages').doc(newMessage.messageid).set(newMessage.toMap());
          print('Message Sent');
          widget.chatroom.lastMessage=msg;
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chatrooms').doc(widget.chatroom.chatroomid).set(widget.chatroom.toMap());
          print('last message created');
        }
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
        return Scaffold(
          appBar:AppBar(
            title: Row(children: [
              CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: NetworkImage(widget.targetUser.profilepic.toString()),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10,),
              Text(widget.targetUser.fullName.toString())
            ],),
          ),
          body: SafeArea(child: Container(
    
            child: Column(children: [Expanded(child: Container(
    
              child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chatrooms').doc(widget.chatroom.chatroomid).collection('messages').orderBy('createdon',descending: true).snapshots(),
                builder: (context,snapshot){
                  if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.active){
                    if(snapshot.hasData){
                      QuerySnapshot dataSnapshot=snapshot.data as QuerySnapshot;
                      return ListView.builder(reverse: true,
                        itemCount: dataSnapshot.docs.length,itemBuilder: (context,index){
                        MessageModel currentMessage=MessageModel.fromMap(dataSnapshot.docs[index].data() as Map<String,dynamic>);
                        return Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10,vertical: 2),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: currentMessage.sender==widget.usermodel.uid?MainAxisAlignment.end:MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2),
                                  decoration:BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                    color: currentMessage.sender==widget.usermodel.uid?Colors.lightGreenAccent:Colors.orange
                                  ),child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Text(currentMessage.text.toString(),style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),),
                                  )),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      },);
                    }
                    else if(snapshot.hasError){
                      return Center(child: Text('An error occurred!'));
                    }
                    else{
                      return Center(
                        child: Text('say hi to your new friend'),
                      );
                    }
                  }else{
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                  }
                },
              ),
    
    
    
    
            )),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10,vertical: 10),
              child: Container(color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                child: Row(
                children: [Flexible(child: TextField(
                  controller:messagecontroller,
                  maxLines: null,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    hintText: 'Enter your message here',
                  ),
                )),
                IconButton(onPressed: (){sendMessage();}, icon: Icon(Icons.send),color: Colors.red,),
                ],
              ),),
            )],),
    
          ),),);
      }
    }
```

The red error it shows on my physical device when i try to run the app..
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
The method 'toDate' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: toDate()

Comment: Maybe the error message is telling you that `map['createdon']` is null.  We can't see why that is.  You're going to have to do some debugging.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that code this post lacks details.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

This means either one or more of the documents you are getting from Firebase does not have a createdon field, or that field has a `null` value. You should check the documents found in your messages collection

Answer (score 0):

change the model to this

"
createdon = map["createdon"] != null ? DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(map['createdon'] as int)
: null;

"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).